# How to set template file for properties files in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

It is easy to set the template for build.xml(Window->Preferences->Ant->Editor->Template), but I could not figure out how to set template for properties file. In Window->Perference, there is not a properties editor->template option at all.

So how could I set the template for properties file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the properties file editor inside eclipse does not have the template file features.

If fact , you can open the the *.properties using any editors with the template file features .Just right click from the editor content ---> Open With ---> Other ---> Internal Editors , and choose the editor with the template feature (eg Ant Editor) .Then , you can use the template files setup in that editor

[image]